# how to display Google Plus average rating on my website?

Tags: google-plus

I want to put Google+ badge of a business on my page. I can get code for it using Google Developer website: https://developers.google.com/+/web/badge/#badge

But i do not understand how to get average score and number of reviews so I can feature them on my website as well - something similar to what you get when you [search for a place](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the%20keg):

[image]

for example, here is a restaurant's Google+ page: https://plus.google.com/106659611775440325701/about?hl=en - it clearly displays all those reviews and scores. How to get this information from Google? Is there a way to modify badge's code to include them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE May 2019**: it is possible now to get total number of reviews using `Place Details` Place APIs call: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields

as of Jan 2019, it returns `user_ratings_total` field: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#335

---

so looking at this again 3 years later, we still can't get all reviews for a place. We can get *some* - top 5 - using Place Details API call: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

then there is a change request for Google team to extend this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825957

And finally, you can [apply for Google Business Account](https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs#request-access) and request access to extended API which allows you to get all reviews for a `verified` location: [accounts.locations.reviews.list](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v3/accounts.locations.reviews/list)

Comment: Wait, you can get the total number of reviews for a location without a Google Business account? What are the downsides to this? I need to implement a feature, but accessing the Google Business accounts is difficult since we have a dozen of them.

Answer (score 1):

Reviews data is part of the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/). There are a couple of options for getting them on your site.

- The [Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) would be the easiest but requires loading a map on your page.
- Using the [Maps JS API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details) you can load and render place details client side.
- Using the [HTTP API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) you can load details on your server to cache in a DB and render on page load.